# Extend an entity from another class?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, entity

We're developing and maintaining a project based on spring framework and java. And we use hibernate implementation for persistance. In some modules of our project we use entities which are identical in almost every way but a few fields. Consider them as two pojos like Sample1 and Sample2. Can i extend them from a Serializable base class like pseudos below:

```
public class Sample implements Serializable{
    SomeType someField;
    .
    .
} 

public class Sample1 extends Sample implements Serializable{

}

public class Sample2 extends Sample implements Serializable{

}
```

And then define the fields of these classes as properties in xml mapping files like:

```
<class name = Sample1 table = SAMPLE1>
    <property name="someField" />
<class name = Sample2 table = SAMPLE2>
    <property name="someField" />
```

Sorry for an old type question for an outdated system :) 
But work must go on...

Regards..

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Good question :) i haven't tried yet just because didnt want to mess up anything.

Comment: That's a bigger problem. You shouldn't be afraid of messing up. Use a version control system. Experiment. If you mess up, revert to the latest commit, and you'll have your original code back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  The mapping for the subclass only needs the new fields, not all of them. YMMV depending on your environment (version of Spring, etc.)

Comment: This is great then. Just wanted to make sure before i try this kind of thing.